# Not to select more than one radio button for different ids

Tags: jquery

I don't to select another radio button if i selected already one radio button for different radio button id's

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
                    if ($(IsCorrectAnswerOption1).is(':checked')) {
                        $("#IsCorrectAnswerOption1").val(true);
                    } else if ($(IsCorrectAnswerOption2).is(':checked')) {
                        $("#IsCorrectAnswerOption2").val(true);
                    }
                    else if ($(IsCorrectAnswerOption3).is(':checked')) {
                        $("#IsCorrectAnswerOption3").val(true);
                    }
                    else if ($(IsCorrectAnswerOption4).is(':checked')) {
                        $("#IsCorrectAnswerOption4").val(true);
                    }
                });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption1" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption1" /> A
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption2" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption2" /> B
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption3" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption3" /> C
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption4" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption4" /> D
```

it is selecting multiple radio buttons aswell and here in my case i need to keep name also different

Comment: you want to select only `one` or `more then one`??

Comment: You should not have this problem with the same name. However do you want to keep different names? quite right ? (Does the name in your case have to be the same as the id?)

Comment: only one but if selecting another one it is selecting that one also

Comment: yes i want to keep name also different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first uncheck everything, and then check the one you have clicked

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').click(function () {
  $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked',false);
  $('input[type="radio"]').val('false');
    $(this).prop('checked','checked');
    $(this).val('true');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption1" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption1" /> A
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption2" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption2" /> B
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption3" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption3" /> C
<input type="radio" class="radio-button" name="IsCorrectAnswerOption4" id="IsCorrectAnswerOption4" /> D
```